# Can't find MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException insert query error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This is the error message

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''')' at line 1'

this is my query

```cs
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into subject(id, code, title, unit) values('" + textBox1.Text + "',''" + textBox2.Text + "',''" + textBox3.Text + "',''" + textBox4.Text + "')", conn);
```

I've been looking over at it for over an hour now and I still get this error.

Comment: I see you have lots of mismatched single-quotes. Do yourself a favor and use parameters instead of concatenating strings. It's much easier to write the code without getting eyestrain counting quote characters, and it's also a safer way to protect against SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Did you check the resulting query formed after executing this line is the correct one? Because I can see `+ " ',' ' " +` here you have mismatched single quotes in the query provided.

Comment: Hi @Vince Garcia, it is recommended to use [Paramaterized Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) as this will simplify to add the values in the query and also prevent [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to use [Parameterized Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html).

**UPDATED**: As suggested by @CodeCaster for the concerns mentioned in [Stop Using AddWithValue()](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) article, I switch all the `AddWithValue()` to `Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType).Value`.

```cs
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into subject(id, code, title, unit) values(@ID, @Code, @Title, @Unit)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.int).Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Varchar, 10).Value = textBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50).Value = textBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = textBox4.Text;
```

And also be sure that the value you pass with the `SqlDbType` **must match the data type as respective database table column**.

The reasons to use Parameterized Query are:

1. It simplifies the query in passing the parameters and makes the query become more readable.
2. Prevent [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Reference: [Prepare MySQL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html)